# Typescript this is something different in function

Tags: angular, typescript

on the top of my component I have declared variable selectedTimeSlot

now, on UI I have chart which calls this method to format X axis

```
dateTickFormatting(val: Moment): string {
    switch(this.selectedTimeSlot) {
      case TimeSlot.Hour:
        return val.format('H');
      case TimeSlot.Day:
        return val.format('D');
      case TimeSlot.Week:
        return val.format('ddd');
      case TimeSlot.Month:
        return val.format('M');
      case TimeSlot.Year:
        return val.format('Y');
    }
  }
```

but `this.selectedTimeSlot` is `undefined`, how can I access my variable inside this function ?

Comment: is your function declared as a class method, or is it just a simple Javascript function ?

Comment: Can you share the wole `.ts` file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
> dateTickFormatting = (val: Moment) => { }
```

If it's in a class it should work with your code piece, if not then probably this gonna solve your issue.

Comment: great it works, can you explain why ?

Comment: This is an "arrow function" which doesn't create it's own scope. When you use a class, it has it's own scope (since it's actually transpiled to a normal function) and the internal methods are are hooked to the prototype.